# Adding Different Category List to View Model C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my web application, I want to show in the view item list separated by their Category_ID.

To do that In my view model I created,

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CakesViewModel> CakesVM { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PizzaViewModel> PizzaVM { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FastFoodsViewModel> FastFoodsVM { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        List<Products> Cakes = db.Products.Where(x=>x.Category_ID == 1).ToList<Products>();
        List<Products> Pizzas = db.Products.Where(x => x.Category_ID == 2).ToList<Products>();
        List<Products> FastFoods = db.Products.Where(x => x.Category_ID == 3).ToList<Products>();
        List<ProductsViewModel> allProducts = new List<ProductsViewModel>();
        
        foreach (Products item in Cakes)
        {
            CakesViewModel productsView = new CakesViewModel();
            productsView.ID = item.ID;
            productsView.ProductPrice = item.ProductPrice;
            productsView.ProductName = item.ProductName;
            productsView.Is_Customizable = item.Is_Customizable;
            productsView.Category_Name = item.FoodCategories.CategoryName;
            productsView.ProductPicture = item.ProductPicture;

            allProducts.Add(productsView);
        }

        foreach (Products item in Pizzas)
        {
            PizzaViewModel productsView = new PizzaViewModel();
            productsView.ID = item.ID;
            productsView.ProductPrice = item.ProductPrice;
            productsView.ProductName = item.ProductName;
            productsView.Is_Customizable = item.Is_Customizable;
            productsView.Category_Name = item.FoodCategories.CategoryName;
            productsView.ProductPicture = item.ProductPicture;

            allProducts.Add(productsView);
        }

        foreach (Products item in FastFoods)
        {
            FastFoodsViewModel productsView = new FastFoodsViewModel();
            productsView.ID = item.ID;
            productsView.ProductPrice = item.ProductPrice;
            productsView.ProductName = item.ProductName;
            productsView.Is_Customizable = item.Is_Customizable;
            productsView.Category_Name = item.FoodCategories.CategoryName;
            productsView.ProductPicture = item.ProductPicture;

            allProducts.Add(productsView);
        }

        return View(allProducts);
}
```

I want to know here can't add items by

```
allProducts.Add(productsView);
```

Want to know how to add `Cakes` list to the `CakesViewModel ,` Pizza`to`PizzaViewModel`` and pass to the view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `allProducts` variable should not be a `List<ProductsViewModel>` type it should be simple object like below

   `ProductsViewModel allProducts = new ProductsViewModel(){`
   `CakesVM =new List<CakesViewModel>()`,
   `PizzaVM =new List<PizzaViewModel>(),`
   `FastFoodsVM =new List<FastFoodsViewModel>(),`

   };
2. You should add Individual items to respective List in each `foreach` loop, like below

   `foreach (Products item in Cakes)`

   ```
    `{`
        `CakesViewModel productsView = new CakesViewModel();`
        `productsView.ID = item.ID;`
        `productsView.ProductPrice = item.ProductPrice;`
        `productsView.ProductName = item.ProductName;`
        `productsView.Is_Customizable = item.Is_Customizable;`
        `productsView.Category_Name = item.FoodCategories.CategoryName;`
        `productsView.ProductPicture = item.ProductPicture;`
        `allProducts.CakesVM.Add(productsView);`
    `}`
   ```
3. Do the respective thing in all threee `foreach` loops.

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer, But still ``allProducts.CakesVM.Add(productsView);`` error in the ``Add`` part.  So then I changed the ViewModel IEnumerable List to ``public List<CakesViewModel> CakesVM { get; set; }`` But when I debug the code null error occurs.

Comment: I have edited the answer to initialize the lists. could you try with the new code.